# Use same gateway on Amazon VPN (VPC)

Tags: amazon-vpc

I'm trying to create a VPN on AWS but it returns an error:

```
Conflict among chosen gateway IP addresses. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidCustomerGateway.DuplicateIpAddress;
```

I was wondering if it's possible to use same Gateway on my account and another account that is not mine. I've make it working when change zone but i would like to use the same region that receive the error.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty certain that is not possible. You need to make a new Customer Gateway with a new IP Address.
A gateway can only map to one IP address.
And the Customer Gateway IP address can only exist once per region, and I mean for the whole region across subscriptions.

Comment: Your answer is probably okay, but I suggest to elaborate more. Why is it so, how should it be done, etc.